# php the_content executes incorrectly if placed after script in html body

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress and using the following to drag the pages content into the html body.

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

It works fine when placed anywhere above the script, but if I place it anywhere on the page after the script, it outputs as though it's an echo function (I'm guessing that what it is) of the same script.

Can anyone tell me what might be going on and if there is a way to stop this from happening. I tried placing the script in a separate page and using the include function to pull it in, but that didn't work either.

```
<?php
$pages = array(
    0 => 'longtailtext/intro1-1.php', 
    1 => 'longtailtext/intro1-2.php'
);
srand(floor(time()/60/60/1));
$key =rand(0,count($pages)-1);
include($pages[$key]) ;
?>
```

Placing the content tag anywhere after the script simply outputs the following:
"longtailtext/paragraph1-1.php"

Thank you for any help you can give me on this :)

Comment: Can you provide the code in the include file? Seems like something in there is causing issues

Comment: Which include file do you mean?

Comment: This one `include($pages[$key]) ;`, the intro1-1 et intro1-2.php

Comment: intro1-1.php intro1-2.php are just some text in <p>text</p> tags

Answer (score 0):

Could be a rogue plugin causing the error. Try this: http://hungred.com/how-to/avoid-trouble-filter-thecontent-wordpress/ from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019325/wordpress-the-content-not-working-on-single-php).

Comment: I'm not writing a plugin though?

Comment: I tried adding this to my own code and all I got was "The content contains: longtailtext/intro1-2.php"

Comment: That link mentioned a few people who had the same problem as you, something about plugins interfering with `the_content`. Sadly I'm no WP expert

Comment: I believe if it was a plugin behind the problem, then the problem would occur anywhere on the page, not just after the custom script I posted here (which as far as I know has no baring on anything plugin related). Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should be using http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content

Comment: Nope that doesn't work AT ALL, doesn't display anything placed anywhere on the site.